# REST API / DELETE METHOD / Slim Framework v3

Tags: php, rest, slim, http-delete

I am currently in the process of learning how to buid my own REST API using the Slim Framework v3 for PHP. I found several tutorials and was able to build multiple routes to send GET and POST requests to my MySQL database.
Next up for me is a delete request, but it doesn’t work.

This is my code:

```
$app->delete('/usuario/[{correo}]', function ($request, $response, $args) {
  $sth = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE email=:correo");
  $sth->bindParam("correo", $args['correo']);
  $sth->execute();
  $todos = $sth->fetchAll();
  return $this->response->withJson($todos);
});
```

I’m testing it in Postman and I always have the same problem: 404 Not found.
I can’t understand it because I think the url is correct (`http://localhost:8080/usuario/bbb@bbb.es`).

[Postman view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUrLz.jpg)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: 404 error occur when page not found or url missing.

Comment: do you have an .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was in the parameter you sent to the route

You can not send dots as a character in your route URL
IF you test
I guess if you test `http://localhost:8080/usuario/bbb@bbbdotes`
It will work fine

You can send the email address in the body not in the url

```
{"email":"bbb@bbbdotes"}
```

And then you can deal with it like POST route to fetch the email address